# How to manually inject NullBooleanField data in form?

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I'm using a widget framework that unfortunately moves some inputs outside the `<form>` tags in the DOM. I'm therefore having to create hidden inputs and then set them with javascript to get them to be passed in `request.POST`.

The trouble is, though I'm using `"Yes"`, `"No"`, and `"Unknown"` values [as per the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#nullbooleanselect), they're getting translated to `None` in `cleaned_data`. Here's an example taken from a couple of print functions in the relevant view:

#### request.POST.urlencode()

`n_var=Yes&n_short=Unknown&p_widget=Unknown&n_long=Yes&verbatim=Blah ...`

#### form.cleaned_data

`{'n_var': None, 'n_short': None, 'p_widget': None, 'n_long': None, 'verbatim': 'Blah' ...`

The form is a `ModelForm`, and saves the fields that aren't `NullBooleanField` fine. Extract:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    n_var = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
    n_short = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
    p_widget = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
    n_long = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)
    verbatim = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=32) #saves fine
```

What's going on? How do I manually get my NullBoolean data into my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget's *display* values are 'Unknown', 'Yes', 'No'.

However, if you look at the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#NullBooleanSelect), you see that the submitted values are '1', '2', and '3' (for 'Unknown', 'Yes', 'No' respectively).

You should use strings for your hidden inputs.

Comment: Oh wow, I did not know that the source was so accessible! You're a saint.